# If I enable proguard then Android gives me this error at release time using v4 support

Tags: android, android-proguard

I enabled the proguard and when I'm releasing apk then proguard generate error. I am using only v4 is it the error?

```
  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
compile project(':library')

compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')

compile project(':com_facebook_android')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

below error:

Information:Gradle tasks [:abc:assembleRelease]

:com_facebook_android:compileLint
:com_facebook_android:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:checkReleaseManifest
:com_facebook_android:prepareReleaseDependencies
:com_facebook_android:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:com_facebook_android:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE

:library:compileLint
:library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:checkReleaseManifest
:library:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareReleaseDependencies
:library:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:library:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:abc:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:abc:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:abc:checkReleaseManifest
:abc:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:abc:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library UP-TO-DATE
:abc:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:abc:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebook430Library UP-TO-DATE
:abc:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:abc:prepareabc_androidAndroidHorizontalListViewUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:abc:prepareabc_androidCom_facebook_androidUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:abc:prepareabc_androidLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:abc:prepareReleaseDependencies
:abc:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:abc:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:abc:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:abc:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:abc:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:abc:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:abc:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:abc:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:abc:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:abc:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:abc:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:abc:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:abc:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:abc:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:abc:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:abc:proguardRelease UP-TO-DATE
:abc:dexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:abc:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:abc:packageRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':abc:packageRelease'.

> Unable to compute hash of /home/dev23/Documents/work_space/abc_android/abc/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/release/classes.jar
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 2.335 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings

```
Information:See complete output in console
    > Unable to compute hash of /home/dev23/Documents/work_space/Abc_android/abc/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/release/classes.jar
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 2.335 secs
    Information:1 error
    Information:0 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Please show us the complete output as hinted in the error  `See complete output in console` and your proguard file

Comment: hello, thanks for response...I have update the question..please verify and let me know...Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that the error from the `Gradle Console`? Did you configure your proguard file?

Comment: is there any way to resolve this issue and how can i enable to progaurd. ?

Comment: Please read the question I linked above and show us your proguard file